# Локализация в windows forms

Tags: .net, winforms, локализация

Добрый вечер. Делаю приложение на windows forms (.NET Framework 4.6). Нужно сделать локализацию.В зависимости от выбранного языка,подключаю соответственный файл ресурсов. Сделала смену языка,но только при перезапуске формы.А при перезапуске данные,которые вводятся сбрасываются. Как можно сделать смену языка без перезапуска формы? Не могли бы привести небольшой примерчик на C++ ?

Comment: Вам нужно будет обновить все контролы.

Comment: Ох, переключение языка на лету в WinForms? Это, как я понимаю, достаточно большая и болезненная проблема. Боюсь, маленького простого решения не выйдет, выйдет большое и сложное.

Comment: @AGS17: А если текст в контрол пришёл из code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте пробежать все контролы на форме и сохранить данные. После смены языка восстановить эти данные.
2. Вы можете задавать текст для Label напрямую из кода, например так:

   ResourceManager LocRM = new ResourceManager("WindowsApplication1.WinFormStrings",typeof(Form1).Assembly);
   label1.text = LocRM.GetString("strMessage");

   Тогда вы можете просто запустить метод, обновляющий надписи после смены языка.
   Если контролов на форме мало, то это оптимальный способ.